# Difference between Workload management and Resource Management in YARN

Tags: hadoop-yarn, hadoop2, cgroups

I am getting confused between the functionalities of Workload management and the resource management. Can anyone clarify this with a real life example?

And, as much as i understand by the concepts, Cgroups can be used in resource management, but is there a role of Cgroups in Workload management? if yes, then how?

Thank you!!!